# Quickbooks PHP WebConnector (Client found response content type of 'text/html

Tags: php, soap, quickbooks

I am using quickbooks webconnector and upon trying to connect i am getting authentication failed, what was the recent change we done is migrated from one server to another server configured database credentials correctly.

THIS COULD BE A POSSIBLE DUPLICATE QUESTION BUT I AM STUCK AT THIS AND NEED SOMEON TO ASSIST, SINCE ITS MAKING NO SENSE.

but logs are showing

**Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'**

Below is the complete log file output.

```
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Password management - Started
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Password management - Ended
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Performing SCHEDULED UPDATE for application = myAppName
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: myAppName
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): myAppName
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: {web-connector-url} ( i have removed for security)
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.3.0.36">
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'myAppName', username = '{my-app-username}'
20201208.22:22:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="{my-app-username}"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20201208.22:22:58 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my dsn format, i used autogenerated password which was putting in special characters leading to messing up with the format

my previous dsn was
mysql://dbusername:password!@#@localhost/dbname  ( here you can see having @ sign was acting as a delimiter hence it was throwing error

changed to
mysql://dbusername:password123@localhost/dbname

And everything worked fine